# Accessing nested JSON element in Javascript without using eval

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have JSON below that I am trying to access.

```
{    
 "orders": {
   "errorData": {
     "errors": {
       "error": [
         {
           "code": "ERROR_01",
           "description": "API service is down"
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   "status": "fail"
 }
}
```

I want to be able to declare constants to refer to the JSON since the structure could change and I don't want to be re-factoring accesses all over the place. Say, I want to access the "status" key and use my constant.  Data refers to the JSON object.  I could try (This is in TypeScript):

```
public static STATUS : string = "data["orders"]["status"]";
var status_value = STATUS;
```

The problem is that this is simply assigning the string STATUS to the variable "status_value", not actually evaluating it.  I could call eval on STATUS, but I want to avoid that.  I know there is a loop answer, but it seems a tad over-kill since I'll be accessing this all over the code. (It's an Angular 2 app so lots of back-end calls and parsing JSON)

I could write the loop function as a constant and call it?  Any advice would be great, as I am new to Javascript.

Comment: and why not just `data['order']['status']`?  I don't understand your use case.  Perhaps you have a legitimate reason, but I don't get it.  Why does it need to be a string, why do you have to evaluate the string?  Why can't you pass the object/values as you want?

Comment: I wanted to put the access in one place and was unaware of passing the object.  Multiple typescript files would need access since there are different services and components.  The answer is a file exporting a class with a static method I can import into the other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the status can't change once loaded then assign the value of `data.orders.status` to a variable and just use that variable throughout your code.

```
public static STATUS : string = data.orders.status;
```

(or whatever the typescript syntax is).

If the status *can* change after the page is loaded then use a function and call that function throughout your code:

```
function getStatus() { return data.orders.status; }
```

Either way the details of the object structure needed to get to the `status` field are only described in one place in the code.

Comment: That short function syntax is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

But I have another idea, why not save the keys in a list and calculate the value by getting those keys' values in order. I don't know TypeScript so I am writing my answer in Javascript, you will get the idea.

```
public static STATUS : string = ["orders", "status"];
var status_value = angular.copy(data);
STATUS.forEach(function(key){
     status_value = status_value[key];
});
```

Comment: @Barton Durbin if you don't want to use `eval` and also don't want to change the way of solvig this problem then why are you posting here